# Shinyapps does not display ggvis graph immediately

Tags: r, ggvis, shiny

I'm creating a markdown document with embeded ggvis charts.
When uploading these charts to ggvis the field remains blank until the black corner of the graph is moved. At that point the graph starts showing.

[image]

How can I make sure the graph is showing from the start?

The following coded is used to generate the graphs:

```
train%>% ggvis(~Survived, opacity := 0.8, fill:= "firebrick") %>%
  layer_bars() %>%
  set_options(width =300, height =300) %>%
  add_axis("x", title = "Non-survivors versus Survivors")
```

The graph is situated in [element 2.2](https://glennterprise.shinyapps.io/Kaggle-Titanic).

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

Based on the input I received in the comments I made the following adjustments:

````
```{r echo = FALSE}
train%>% ggvis(~Survived, opacity := 0.8, fill:= "firebrick") %>%
  layer_bars() %>%
  set_options(width =300, height =300) %>%
  add_axis("x", title = "Non-survivors versus Survivors") %>% 
  bind_shiny("PlotSurvived")
```

```{r echo = FALSE}
ggvisOutput("PlotSurvived")
```
````

The result is that the application tries to load the graph twice. Once for the first code chunk. In this case the problem remains the same.

The second code chunk load successfully.

An additional question rises:

How can I create the graph without displaying it in chunck one? And the using     `ggvisOutput("PlotSurvived")`to display it?

Would this be the best practice?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments and guidelines provided by user10853 I managed to created a 'dirty' workaround. The solution that worked in my case can be found below.

```
{r, echo = FALSE, results = "hide"}
train%>% ggvis(~Survived, opacity := 0.8, fill:= "firebrick") %>%
  layer_bars() %>%
  set_options(width =300, height =300) %>%
  add_axis("x", title = "Non-survivors versus Survivors") %>% 
  bind_shiny("PlotSurvived")
```

By setting `echo = FALSE` R Markdown will not display the code in the final document (but it will still run the code and display its results unless told otherwise). This is what you need in order to make sure the plot gets generated within the code and that the `bind_shiny()` element get executed.

By setting `result = FALSE` R Markdown will not display the results of the code (but it will still run the code and display the code itself unless told otherwise).

This means `echo`ensures the code does not get displayed while `result` ensures the 'broken' graph doesn't gets displayed.

I follow up with this piece of code in order to generate the working graph.

````
```{r echo = FALSE}
ggvisOutput("PlotSurvived")
```
````

Answer (score 0):

It shows just fine. I just viewed it in my phone. Maybe it's your browser?

[image]

Update: I just checked it in Chrome and it is as your report. Try setting the dimensions of the graph manually.

Comment: Hi, thank you for checking. What exactly do you mean with 'setting the dimensions of the graph manually?'. I'll update the question with the code from one of the gaphs. Firefox handles everything well. Chrome and Safari have issues apparently.

Comment: I mean to set the height and width. I guess you left it to automatically set them. I am just assuming this might solve the problem.

Comment: Hi, I update the initial question by adding a snippet of code used to generate the graphs. As you can see height and width are already specified. The issue still remains.

Comment: I think you need to assign the plot command to a variable. Just add a variable before "train" and assign it to it. Then use that var as an argument to ggvisOutput(" var").

Comment: @glnvdl add the following as a last line to the above code: "%>% bind_shiny("var")". Then add to your document: ggvisOutput("var").

Comment: Thank you for the input. I updated the initial question above with the results!

Comment: So you got the graph working?
Moreover, try combining both chunks in one. That is remove the middle part:

   ``
   
   ```{r echo = FALSE}
If it still doesn't work try putting the ggvisOutput() before the plotting code.
If this solves your question please mark as solved.

Comment: Tried to apply your suggestion. Both plots still get displayed. One not working immediately, one working immediately (ggvisOutput). Still not fixed.

Comment: I am not sure why this happens. A quick & dirty solution is to keep both code chunks as separate like before but for the first hide the result: ```{r, results='hide', echo=F}.
That should make it work.

Comment: Actually I was creating that answer at the same time you answered. You can find my solution above. I'm pretty sure this is a dirty workaround. But currently it's the only one that works...